# How can I use a java interface to calculate the union, intersection, and difference of two sets, all in a default method in the interface?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, interface, set

I am new to java so sorry if this is super basic. I need to make default methods in an interface ISet to allow for the calculation of the union, intersection, and difference of 2 sets created in a class that implements this interface. I know how to calculate all of these but I have no idea how to syntactically do it in the interface since it uses interface objects rather than the data structures in the implementing classes.

The Code:

```
public interface ISet {

void add(Integer val);

Integer removePos(int pos);

boolean contains(Integer val);

int getSize();

default void union(ISet unionWith) {
    //List<Integer>unionSet = new ArrayList<>();
    //unionSet.add(unionWith);
    //List set = new ArrayList();
    //set.addAll(0, unionWith);
    //ISet unionSet = this;
    // To call in main: this.union(unionWith)
    // For my variables it would be mySet.union(mySet2)
    //this.getSize();
    int size1 = this.getSize();
    int size2 = unionWith.getSize();
    if(this == unionWith) {

    }
    //List<Integer> unionList = Arrays.asList(this);
    ISet allVals = this.add(Integer val);
    for(int i = 0; i < size1 + size2; i++) {
        if(!this.contains(Integer.unionWith));
    }
}

default void intersect(ISet intWith) {

}

default void difference(ISet diffWith) {

}
```

}

Sorry for the graveyard I'm just trying every thing I can. Pretty much none of this works except for the size stuff. I know that I'm supposed to use all of the other methods above but I have no idea how to use them in this scenario.

I usually try and figure out things like this by myself but after 3 hours of not being able to union two sets I've realized that I just need to get more informed on how java and interfaces work.

I'll really appreciate any help you guys have to offer!

Comment: The interface needs at least one non-default method to retrieve the items contained in the set (otherwise you would have to test for every possible integer if it is contained).

Comment: I assume the questions is about the `union` method since you haven't posted any code for the other methods? What (compiler-) errors are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need a methed : Integer get(int pos);

```
public interface ISet {

void add(Integer val);

Integer get(int pos);

Integer removePos(int pos);

boolean contains(Integer val);

int getSize();

default void union(ISet unionWith) {
    for (int i = 0; i < unionWith.getSize(); i++) {
        this.add(unionWith.get(i));
    }
}

default void intersect(ISet intWith) {
    for (int i = getSize() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        Integer value = get(i);
        if (!intWith.contains(value)) {
            removePos(i);
        }
    }
}

default void difference(ISet diffWith) {
    for (int i = getSize() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        Integer value = get(i);
        if (diffWith.contains(value)) {
            removePos(i);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Ok this has helped me out a LOT but now I am getting index out of bounds exceptions when removePos is called. Not sure if it's the loops in the interface or the implementations in the classes but I don't think that's the case since removePos has worked fine until now

Comment: Ok I actually fixed everything besides the intersect function

Comment: In fact, your interface is not designed properly. Since it is a Set, there should be no concept of "position".

"Integer removePos(int pos);" should be changed to "Integer remove(Integer value);"

"Integer get(int pos);" should actually be "Iterator<Integer> iterator();"

Comment: The assignment requires that we use an array class and a list class to do all of this and we aren't allowed to use built in sets at all

Comment: Even if you use the array implementation behind it, ISet should still have the correct signature. The implementation behind it should not affect the signature of the interface.